# How to add a recent version of libsdl2 to my Travis CI build?

Tags: travis-ci, sdl-2

The libsdl2 packages in trusty are too old for my project. So I have tried something along those lines, but am having nothing but trouble (as then libpng >= 1.6 seems to be needed, etc. pp. ad infinitum):

```
install:
 - export CXX="g++-7"
  - if [ "${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}" = "linux" ]; then
      wget http://libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.7.tar.gz
      && tar -xzvf SDL2-2.0.7.tar.gz
      && pushd SDL2-2.0.7 && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install && popd;
    fi
  - if [ "${TRAVIS_OS_NAME}" = "linux" ]; then
      wget https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-2.0.2.tar.gz
      && tar -xzvf SDL2_image-2.0.2.tar.gz
      && pushd SDL2_image-2.0.2 && ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && sudo make install && popd;
    fi
```

So, I'd like to pursue a different avenue.  What I am wondering is, if there isn't some way of doing something like

```
sudo apt-get install -t unstable libsdl2-dev
```

as I would do in a normal Debian system? On Travis CI, however, this does not work as no such repositories exist - only trusty does.  (And yes, there is zoogie/sdl2-snapshots, but that is also too old.)

I looked at the Ubuntu archives and it seems that zesty is already recent enough to have the libsdl2 versions I require.  Perhaps I can somehow include those? But how?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I explicitly download, build and install a specific version of sdl2 in the `before_install` section:

```
# Download, make and install SDL2-2.0.8 (stable)
- |
  travis_retry curl -L https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.8.tar.gz | tar xz
  cd SDL2-2.0.8
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
```

This should work with `language: c`.